# Calling IBAction Programmatically in TableViewHeader

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uibutton, uitableview

I am creating a button pro-grammatically in my TableView Header cell and adding TouchUpInside Action to it. With UIButton Header contains two other UILabels also.

Problem : If Button Is added as SubView, Its not respondin.

But when I return only UIButton from Method It is working fine.

Here is my code of `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section`

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{


UIView *viewHeader = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 60)];

viewHeader.tag = 101;

viewHeader.backgroundColor = [UIColor cyanColor];


UIButton *btnBack = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

btnBack.frame = CGRectMake(15, 15, 50, 25);

//btnBack.titleLabel.text = @"Back";
[btnBack setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[btnBack addTarget:self action:@selector(Back:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
btnBack.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

UILabel *lblPlayerName = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 20, 60, 20)];
lblPlayerName.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

UILabel *lblHighScoreOfPlayer = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(215, 20, 80, 20)];
lblHighScoreOfPlayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];


}
lblPlayerName.text = [@"Name" uppercaseString];

lblHighScoreOfPlayer.text = [@"Scores" uppercaseString];

[viewHeader addSubview:btnBack];    
[viewHeader addSubview:lblPlayerName];
[viewHeader addSubview:lblHighScoreOfPlayer];

return viewHeader;


}
```

Comment: put a break point in your back method because you code seems to be right.

Comment: Its Done, But Action is not calling as button is not responding !!!

Comment: why you have written this line btnBack.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
 the default property is already yes

Comment: Try to set `viewHeader.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`

Comment: An UIImageView is intended for displaying one image or series of them, not for labels or buttons. Have you tried a plain UIView instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you add the image view as a subView of uiview for header view instead of
 `UIView *viewHeader = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 60)];`

The procedure should be in the following order.

step1.allocate UIView
step2:add imageView as the subView of uiView
step3:add the button as the subview of imageview
then return the uiview

This is a working code i tested.

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    UIView *headerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 30)] autorelease];
    UIButton *btnBack = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    btnBack.frame = CGRectMake(15, 15, 50, 25);


    [btnBack setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [btnBack addTarget:self action:@selector(Back:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    btnBack.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    [headerView addSubview: btnBack];
    return headerView;
}
```

Comment: I added the imageview but not fruitfull.....The button is still not responding !!!

Comment: - (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
 UIView *headerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 30)] autorelease];
UIButton *btnBack = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
 
 btnBack.frame = CGRectMake(15, 15, 50, 25);
 
 
 [btnBack setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 
 [btnBack addTarget:self action:@selector(Back:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 btnBack.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
 
  [headerView addSubview: btnBack];
 return headerView;
}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but probably you should set property `userInteractionEnabled` for your main `UIView` `viewHeader.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`.

And as mentions @ott try to allocate `UIView` not `UIImageView` for `viewHeader`:

```
UIView *viewHeader = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 60)];
```

Try it. Hope, it will help you

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but setting userInteractionEnabled to YES is also not working !!!